# React Router v6 redirect when there are not any url queryString parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need the router redirects to the page `"/"` when the URL doesn't have any queryString parameters (`"/domain/search"`). But if it has any, for example `"/domain/search?keyword=something&page=1"`, it should go on and render the component `Movies`.

My code below doesn't work, it still redirects to `"/"` even if the URL has some queryString parameters.

Please help with this problem.

```js
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
    <Route index element={<Search />} />
    <Route path="search" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
    <Route path="search/*" element={<Movies />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-search-params) in the `Movies` component to read the query string in the URL:

1. The Routes:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
    <Route index element={<Search />} />
    <Route path="search" element={<Movies />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

2. the `Movies` component:

```js
import { Navigate, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";


function Movies(props) {

  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const page = searchParams.get("page");
  const otherParam = searchParams.get("otherParam");

  if(!page && !otherParam) {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />
  }

  // the rest of your component
  ...

}
```

[image: Edit restless-wildflower-959qx6]

Or using [`URLSearchParams.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/keys)

```
import { Navigate, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

function Movies() {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  if (![...searchParams.keys()].length) {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
  }

  return <span>Movies page</span>;
}
```

[image: Edit red-meadow-urtrbn]

Answer (score 1):

`react-router-dom` and the `Route` component doesn't use or reference the URL queryString when matching routes. This is something the routed component should check or something you can create a special layout route component to handle. The code should use the [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-search-params) hook to access the `searchParams` and check for the existence of any params.

Example:

This example is a layout route that checks the search params entries array length and if there are entries an `Outlet` component is rendered for any nested `Route` components to render their `element` prop out on, otherwise a redirect back to `"/"` is rendered.

```
import { Navigate, Outlet, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ParamsRoute = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  
  return searchParams.entries().length
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/" replace />
};
```

Usage:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
    <Route index element={<Search />} />
      <Route element={<ParamsRoute />}>
        <Route path="search" element={<Movies />} />
      </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Perhaps you want specific queryString parameters to be present:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ParamsRoute = ({ params = [] }) => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  
  return searchParams.entries().length                // has params
    && params.every(param => searchParams.get(param)) // has required params
      ? <Outlet />
      : <Navigate to="/" replace />
};
```